# Failing to Write Any Query using MongoDB Atlas Search Index

Tags: mongodb-atlas-search

I get this error when I try to run any aggregation using $search in a MongoDB Atlas Search index.

```
Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: Error connecting to localhost:28000 (127.0.0.1:28000) :: caused by :: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that if I created my search index and gave it a name that is not `default` I need to ensure that I include the index name in the query.

```
  {
      "$search": {
         "index": "parks_and_recreation", 
         "equals": {
            "path": "open",
            "value": true
         }
      }
    }
```